# Qual é a diferença entre Settings e Resource?

Tags: c#

`Settings` salva as preferências do usuário para o esquema de cores de um aplicativo por exemplo e o `Resource` serve para a mesma coisa ?

Quando devo usar `Settings` e quando devo usar `Resource` na aplicação Winforms  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A grande diferença é que ao utilizar `Resource` após alterar algum valor, adicionar ou remover uma key, você precisa recompilar a aplicação. Então `Resources` deve ser utilizado para conteúdos mais "estáticos" como textos, labels e outros itens apresentados na UI, principalmente quando se tem variações de cultura (diversos idiomas). Ou seja, deve ser utilizado para a apresentação de recursos relacionados ao core da sua aplicação.

Já através de `Settings` você tem uma maior flexibilidade para configurações relativas a uma distribuição para customizações mais dinâmicas em relação à preferências do usuário ou do que você pretende alterar para um cliente em específico sem depender de uma redistribuição da sua aplicação. Aí entram outras variáveis do sistema, como: strings de conexão, mapeamento de diretórios e etc.

No seu caso, se o objetivo é permitir que o usuário escolha uma paleta de core pré-definida, esses temas podem estar no `Resource` e você guarda no `Settings` qual foi o tema escolhido.

Comment: Onde fica armazenado o Resource ? Depois da instalação do software.

Comment: Ele é compilado junto à aplicação